# What to do if easytag v. 2.4.2 corrupts flac files when saving an image to the metadata?

Tags: ubuntu, flac

I experienced that my `easytag` `version 2.4.2` has a bug which lets it corrupt `flac` files when trying to save a picture to them. It seems to depend on the size of the picture, smaller ones might work (e.g. below 30kB).

Since I am not able to install the latest version 2.4.3. and I also don't know if this would solve the problem I need a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to use `metaflac` to add the picture.

This way `easytag` can still be of use for the tags and no additional software is needed.

Assume you are in the directory where the `flac` files are, the following script can be executed. It saves a backup of the original files outside the directory, removes old metadata and adds one `jpg` to all files.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FILEPATH="/home/$USER/Desktop/coverart.jpg"

echo "**********************************************"
echo "** do 'metaflac --import-picture-from=$FILEPATH FILE'"
CURRENT_CD="${PWD##*/}"

if [ ! -d "../BACKUP" ]; then
  echo "** mkdir ../BACKUP"
  mkdir ../BACKUP
  else echo "** ../BACKUP already exists (directory)"
fi

if [ ! -d "../BACKUP/$CURRENT_CD" ]; then
  echo "** mkdir ../BACKUP/$CURRENT_CD"
  mkdir "../BACKUP/$CURRENT_CD"
  else
    echo "** ../BACKUP/$CURRENT_CD already exists (directory)"
fi

echo ""
for f in *.flac;
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    echo "$f"
    if [ ! -f "../BACKUP/$CURRENT_CD/$f" ]; then
      echo "-> cp $f to ../BACKUP/CURRENT_CD"
      cp "$f" "../BACKUP/$CURRENT_CD/$f"
    else 
      echo "-> backup file already exists" 
    fi
    echo "-> remove old pictures and tag COVERART"
    metaflac --remove --block-type=PICTURE,PADDING --dont-use-padding "$f"
    metaflac --remove-tag=COVERART  --dont-use-padding "$f"
    echo "-> add picture $FILEPATH"
    metaflac --import-picture-from="$FILEPATH" "$f"
  fi
done
echo "***********************************************"
```